# How do I rearrange the order of a list on a web page based on the current day?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm working on a web site for a restaurant and the Daily Specials list takes up too much vertical space.  Each `<li>` consists of the day of the week, name of the special, and a description.

I'd like to encapsulate the list using [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html).

However, this would require the user to scroll to find out what the special for that day is.

So, I want to have the special for the current day always be present at the top, with the other specials listed below.  For example, if today is Wednesday, the list would be ordered as follows:

- Wednesday
- Thursday
- Friday
- Saturday
- Sunday
- Monday
- Tuesday

The specials will not change for the foreseeable future.  Currently I have them in an unordered list (`<ul>`).  What would be the best method to achieve this?

Comment: Can you use any server side code? If so, what language?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing I can think of would be to duplicate today's special above the list of daily specials.

For example, you could create a new empty div above the daily specials with the id todaysSpecial.  Then you could copy the content from the li into that container.

```
$('#todaysSpecial').
  html($($('#specials>li')[new Date().getDay()]).html())
```

The new Date().getDay() function will return an integer between 0 and 6, so the daily specials would need to be listed Sunday-to-Saturday. A little modulo arithmetic would allow you to change which day of the week the list started on.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have them in an array like the following:

```
$specials = array(
  'Monday' => array(...),
  'Tuesday' => array(...),
  'Wednesday' => array(...),
  ...
  'Sunday' => array(...)
);
```

You can take advantage of [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and the `N` formatter to off-set the array based on the day. Then dump the array as you normally would. e.g. http://www.ideone.com/Pb0ys

```
$today = (int)date('N') - 1; // 1=Monday, ..., 7=Sunday
$specials = array_merge(
  array_slice($specials,$today),   // start with today+rest of week
  array_slice($specials,0,$today)  // move specials before today to the end
);
```

Comment: If you're not looking for a PHP solution, you can use javascript and move around the `<ul>` headings (with `<li>` bodies) using the same logic.

Answer (score 0):

I would just rearrange the list according to what day it is, should'nt be to hard.

```
<h1>Specials</h1><br />

<ul id="specials">
    <li id="day0">Sunday : Chinese</li>
    <li id="day1">Monday : Chicken</li>
    <li id="day2">Tuesday : Beef</li>
    <li id="day3">Wednesday : Cod</li>
    <li id="day4">Thursday : Salmon</li>
    <li id="day5">Friday : Taco</li>
    <li id="day6">Saturday : Pizza</li>
</ul>
```

Rearranging like so:

```
var a = new Date().getDay();

for (var i=0; i<=6; i++) {
    if (a==7) {a=0}
    $("#specials").append( $("#day"+a) );
    a++;
}
```

Here's a fiddle to show how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/twU3m/

Comment: Thank you to everyone who responded!  I was unable to work on this until tonight and I managed to get it working using adeneo's code.  You're all awesome!